# Firebase is returning null instead of data

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to retrieve saved data in firebase real-time database, but the result is always `null`.

Below is the code.

```
    try{
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        myBal.setText("0");
        mDatabase.child("users").child(mUserId).child("claim").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String amount  = dataSnapshot.child("satoshi").getValue(String.class);
                myBal.setText("satoshi: "+amount);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Below is my database structure...

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you're not actually reaching the "satoshi" node.

The `ValueEventListener` on the "claim" node returns a `DataSnapshot` representing the "claim" node. There is no "satoshi" child on the "claim" node, the only child is "-Kbvm.....".

You would need to either have the "-Kbvm....." key already and use that to properly follow the path to "satoshi" or else use a ChildEventListener on the "claim" node to get the children of "claim" rather than "claim" itself.